# Create JUnit tests for a card validating method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, functional-testing

I created a Java method that takes a card number and an expiry date and validates the card.
I used Luhn's algorithm for validating the card number.

```
public static boolean isValidCreditCard(String cardNumber, String expiryDate) {
    if (cardNumber.length() != 16) {
        return false;
    }

    int[] digits = new int[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        char digitChar = cardNumber.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isDigit(digitChar)) {
            return false;
        }
        digits[i] = Character.getNumericValue(digitChar);
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
        int digit = digits[i];

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            digit *= 2;

            if (digit > 9) {
                digit -= 9;
            }
        }

        sum += digit;
    }

    if (sum % 10 != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        Date expiry = dateFormat.parse(expiryDate);
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        return expiry.after(currentDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create tests for this method and implement them in JUnit.
I need to create them using equivalence partitioning, boundary value analysis and cause-effect graphing. So I should have 3 sets of tests, one for each testing technique, but I have a hard time figuring out how to divide the tests between the different sets.

I tried making the equivalence classes and it resulted in the tests below. I'm curious about what sets of tests should I choose for boundary value analysis and cause-effect graphing.

These are my tests so far:

```
@Test
void testValidCard() {
    String cardNumber = "4140496470751796";
    String expiryDate = "02/25";
    assertTrue(CardValidator.isValidCreditCard(cardNumber, expiryDate));
}

@Test
void testCardNumberTooShort() {
    String cardNumber = "4615241";
    String expiryDate = "08/24";
    assertFalse(CardValidator.isValidCreditCard(cardNumber, expiryDate));
}

@Test
void testCardNumberTooLong() {
    String cardNumber = "42518293883012154802";
    String expiryDate = "05/24";
    assertFalse(CardValidator.isValidCreditCard(cardNumber, expiryDate));
}

@Test
void testCardNumberInvalidDigits() {
    String cardNumber = "4140ab4398603587";
    String expiryDate = "12/24";
    assertFalse(CardValidator.isValidCreditCard(cardNumber, expiryDate));
}

@Test
void testCardNumberInvalid() {
    String cardNumber = "4064249483030546";
    String expiryDate = "05/24";
    assertFalse(CardValidator.isValidCreditCard(cardNumber, expiryDate));
}

@Test
void testCardExpiryDateBadFormat() {
    String cardNumber = "5416151244634950";
    String expiryDate = "11-2025";
    assertFalse(CardValidator.isValidCreditCard(cardNumber, expiryDate));
}

@Test
void testCardExpired() {
    String cardNumber = "5443965499742482";
    String expiryDate = "01/23";
    assertFalse(CardValidator.isValidCreditCard(cardNumber, expiryDate));
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do your tests pass? Do you expect them to pass?

Comment: Yes, the tests that I have currently pass. My question is what tests should I consider if I want to use the boundary value analysis and cause-effect graphing techniques?

Comment: I think you've covered your bases. I'd change the test of the too short number to have 15 digits, and make sure the too long number has 17 (I didn't count how much you have), to be right next to the boundary. You'll get a NPE if card number or expiration date are `null`, so check the requirements if you want to have that NPE or rather return `false`. Personally I'm not a fan of formal test methods. Find a code coverage tool to show what parts of the code are not tested. Think about whether that code can remain untested (e.g., tested a the caller's site) or needs tests.